# Golang Opc UA Client Implementation with Certificate

Tags: go, opc-ua

I am trying to connect my local Kepware OPC UA server with certificate. OPC UA server security info:
[image]

In golang app , I use "github.com/gopcua/opcua/ua" opc client package. I create key pair and I give them path to variables and used them in config:

```
    opts := []opcua.Option{
            opcua.SecurityPolicy(relatedConnection.SecurityPolicy),
            opcua.SecurityModeString(relatedConnection.SecurityMode),
            opcua.CertificateFile(certFile),
            opcua.PrivateKeyFile(keyFile),
            opcua.AutoReconnect(true),
            opcua.ReconnectInterval(time.Second * 5),
            opcua.RequestTimeout(time.Second * 3),
        }
```

When security policy and mode are none, I can connect to the server without any problem. When I chose these security policies I don't know how to implement code or ssl key pair to connect server.

Comment: Do you have an X.509 certificate or do you want to generate it in the opcua client?

Comment: I want to generate it in the opcua client.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use any security policy above None/None or to use a username/password login, you need to either have an existing X.509 certificate or generate one yourself.

Note, the certificate comes in two parts, a public certificate and a private key.  You need both.  The public certificate will be sent to the Kepware server while the private key will stay with the client and be used for encryption and decryption.

```
endpoints, err := opcua.GetEndpoints(context.Background(), cfg.Endpoint)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("OPC GetEndpoints: %w", err)
}

policy := ua.SecurityPolicyURINone // Replace this with a constant of your security policy
mode := ua.MessageSecurityModeNone // Replace this with a constant of your security mode
ep := opcua.SelectEndpoint(endpoints, policy, mode)

c, err := generateCert() // This is where you generate the certificate
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("generateCert: %w", err)
}

pk, ok := c.PrivateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey) // This is where you set the private key
if !ok {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid private key")
}

cert := c.Certificate[0]
opts := []opcua.Option{
    opcua.SecurityPolicy(policy),
    opcua.SecurityMode(mode),
    opcua.PrivateKey(pk), 
    opcua.Certificate(cert),  // Set the certificate for the OPC UA Client
    opcua.AuthUsername(cfg.Username, cfg.Password), // Use this if you are using username and password
    opcua.SecurityFromEndpoint(ep, ua.UserTokenTypeUserName),
    opcua.SessionTimeout(30 * time.Minute),
    opcua.AutoReconnect(true),
    opcua.ReconnectInterval(time.Second * 10),
    opcua.Lifetime(30 * time.Minute),
    opcua.RequestTimeout(3 * time.Second),
}
```

Use the following to generate the X.509 certificate.

```
func generateCert() (*tls.Certificate, error) {

    priv, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate private key: %s", err)
    }

    notBefore := time.Now()
    notAfter := notBefore.Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour) // 1 year

    serialNumberLimit := new(big.Int).Lsh(big.NewInt(1), 128)
    serialNumber, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, serialNumberLimit)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate serial number: %s", err)
    }

    template := x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber: serialNumber,
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            Organization: []string{"Test Client"},
        },
        NotBefore: notBefore,
        NotAfter:  notAfter,

        KeyUsage:              x509.KeyUsageContentCommitment | x509.KeyUsageKeyEncipherment | x509.KeyUsageDigitalSignature | x509.KeyUsageDataEncipherment | x509.KeyUsageCertSign,
        ExtKeyUsage:           []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth, x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth},
        BasicConstraintsValid: true,
    }

    host := "urn:testing:client"
    if ip := net.ParseIP(host); ip != nil {
        template.IPAddresses = append(template.IPAddresses, ip)
    } else {
        template.DNSNames = append(template.DNSNames, host)
    }
    if uri, err := url.Parse(host); err == nil {
        template.URIs = append(template.URIs, uri)
    }

    derBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, &template, &template, publicKey(priv), priv)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create certificate: %s", err)
    }

    certBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    if err := pem.Encode(certBuf, &pem.Block{Type: "CERTIFICATE", Bytes: derBytes}); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to encode certificate: %s", err)
    }

    keyBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    if err := pem.Encode(keyBuf, pemBlockForKey(priv)); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to encode key: %s", err)
    }

    cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(certBuf.Bytes(), keyBuf.Bytes())
    return &cert, err
}
```

Here is an example directly from the gopcua project:
https://github.com/gopcua/opcua/blob/main/examples/crypto/generate_cert.go

Comment: But it create new certificate every run and thats why OPC UA Configuration Manager adds new Trusted Clients. I should sign as "Trust" the certificate on OPC UA Configuration Manager. When signed the certificate as trusted and run the client again it create new untrusted certificate. It is a loop.

Comment: If you already have a certificate, you can just load it as a file into a `byte[]`.  Look at the crypto example I provided the link to.

Comment: Ok but, How can I get created certificate and private key to load them again. I need their filepath to use "opcua.CertificateFile(cert file path)" or for private key. It loads certificate to OPC UA Maneger as '.der' but How can I use it.

Comment: It requires cert and private key, I can get cer from OPC UA Client Manager but how can get private key for it? This is the error when I load cert from file  : "opcua: invalid channel config: Security policy 'http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#Basic256Sha256' requires a private key""

Comment: You need to generate the certificate and the private key.  There are many ways of doing this.  I do it with an executable provided by the OPC Foundation.  The Go code above also does it.

Comment: For Go, I assume that you can just write the `c` and `pk` variables to their appropriate files: .der and .pfx.  This is just a guess.  With Go, I only done the above.

Comment: @oakkose In my case, opcua's client provided me with both cert.der and pk.pem which are stored in S3 from where I am fetching them.